# Condition for a graph to have only one MST (Minimum Spanning Tree)?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Can somebody tell me if there is a condition for an edge-weighted graph to have exactly one MST?

I know that it can have more minimum spanning trees, but can it have only one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If a graph is a tree, then it has only one minimum spanning tree. Otherwise, a connected graph that is not a tree always has more than one spanning tree.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews he asked about *minimum* spanning trees

Comment: To add to Tom's remark: non-tree graphs always have more than one spanning tree, but not necessarily more than one MST. A cyclic graph, for instance, whose smallest-weight edge is unique, has only one MST.

Comment: @user3491648 Ah, yes, misread. My answer for trees is obviously still true, and, if all edges are the same weight, the rest of the comment is still true, too.

Comment: so the condition would be: all edges must have different weights? In this way it will have only one MST?

Comment: That condition is sufficient, but it's not clear that it's necessary.